# Clean array of object depending from two propreties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object like this:

```
const obj1 = [{
   id: null,
   val: 1
},{
   id: 123,
   val: 1
},{
   id: 456,
   val: 2
},{
   id: null,
   val: 3
}];
```

I need to check when property 'val' is never double, and in case one of those is double should keep the object that have the 'id' not to null. To explain me better the result of the array should be like:

```
[{
   id: 123,
   val: 1
},{
   id: 456,
   val: 2
},{
   id: null,
   val: 3
}];
```

Thanks for helping me with that.

Comment: I'm confused. So if there is a duplicate you want to keep the duplicate's `val` ?

Comment: Can you show some example of what you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a shorter way, but you can definitely pull this off using a `reduce`:

```js
const obj1 = [{
   id: null,
   val: 1
},{
   id: 123,
   val: 1
},{
   id: 456,
   val: 2
},{
   id: null,
   val: 3
}];

const result = obj1.reduce((res, item) => {
    // Find index of item with same "val" if any.
    const index = res.findIndex(x => x.val === item.val)
    if (res[index]) {
        // If there was item with same "val", but null ID, replace it, otherwise do nothing:
        if (res[index].id === null) res[index] = item;
    } else {
        // Otherwise just add to array.
        res.push(item);
    }
    
    return res;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and check if the value is not in the map or if the `id` is null, then set the map with the actual object.

```js
var array = [{ id: null, val: 1 }, { id: 123, val: 1 }, { id: 456, val: 2 }, { id: null, val: 3 }],
    map = new Map(),
    result;
    
array.forEach(o => (!map.has(o.val) || map.get(o.val).id === null) && map.set(o.val, o));

result = [...map.values()];

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```